# Git commit line length constraints

Tags: git

I'm quite new to emacs and a lot of the documentation I'm finding online is going over my head a bit at the moment.

I've been using emacs as my git editor for a while now by mostly eye-balling reasonable line lengths but it's not at the point where I want to have line lengths taken care of for me. I'm not yet at the point of using emacs as my shell environment so I'm looking for a simple solution to simply handle the recommended line lengths (50 chars for the summary line, and 75 chars for all other lines)

I found [this EmacsWiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GitCommitMode) which explains that there's a `log-edit.el` bundled with emacs by default. I'd rather not pull in a large package like magit while I'm still getting to grips with things but I can't find any explanation of how to enable the git log editing mode with `log-edit.el`

**My question is two fold, does `log-edit.el` enforce these recommended line lengths some how (some sort of colour change perhaps), and if so how would I enable it in my emacs config / git config so that it is used for editing git commits?**

If log-edit doesn't have this capability, I'm open to further suggestions or I will take a look at getting started with magit. I'd just like to avoid overloading myself with too much to learn all at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

magit is *completely* worth the effort, and you should start using it as soon as possible. ;)

That said, you can install the `git-commit` part of magit separately using MELPA (https://melpa.org/#/git-commit)

Comment: May as well bite the bullet then, I feel like I'm picking up JavaScript for the first time with all these modules and package managers haha. Thanks for the link to the git-commit part!

Comment: I just tried out MELPA and it was super simple, I've decided to go with git-commit first and then start with magit as soon as I've got to grips with general emacs usage which hopefully won't be long! Thanks for the suggestion about MELPA.

Comment: My pleasure! Have fun. There are a lot of great packages on MELPA.